# How to define a scale with intervals with d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have theese categories :

```
    var IMCcat = [
        {color:'#F43E3E',min:40,max:200,name:'obésité morbide ou massive'},
        {color:'#F4B4B4',min:35,max:40,name:'obésité sévère'},
        {color:'#FAE9CA',min:30,max:35,name:'obésité modérée'},
        {color:'#FFFFD4',min:25,max:30,name:'surpoids'},
        {color:'#E9FFDA',min:18.5,max:25,name:'corpulence normale'},
        {color:'#FFFFD4',min:16.5,max:18.5,name:'maigreur'},
        {color:'#F43E3E',min:0,max:16.5,name:'famine'}
    ];
```

(Theese are Body Mass Index (BMI), but in french (IMC))

As you can see, my domain goes from 0 to 200, but the different categories have different widths.

I would like to define a scale with d3, the domain would be the BMI and the range, the color. Colors are discrete values, but the domain is continuous.

I need to provide the weight to the scale, and get the relative color. It would even be better if, provided the weight, i get the object containing color and name (alongside with min and max but useless).

If you want to try, here is the BMI function:

```
    function BMI(weight) {
        return weight / (height * height);
    }
```

As ranges overlap, how could i set that the minimum is excluded or included, and the max is the opposite ?

Thank you

It's okay if the scale is given the BMI, not the weight. I'll wrap my scale in a function which does the conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [threshold scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#threshold-scales):

```
//reverse array so BMI is ascending 
IMCcat = IMCcat.reverse();

//create scale
var scale = d3.scale.threshold()
  //set the domain equal to the min weights, w/ lowest removed
  .domain(IMCcat.map(function(d){ return d.min; }).slice(1))
  //set the range equal to the colors
  .range(IMCcat.map(function(d){ return d.color; }))
```

The scale converts BMI to color:

```
> scale(40)
"#F43E3E"
> scale(30)
"#FAE9CA"
```

To create a scale the converts BMI to an object w/ color and name, just change the range of the scale:

```
> scale.range(IMCcat)
> scale(20)
Object {color: "#E9FFDA", min: 18.5, max: 25, name: "corpulence normale"}
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect, i've already used threshold scales but i never thought i could use several values.